# Does datatable filter results from database or just from the fetched result?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am working on the datatables integration in php and mysql and I am confuse about that when I filter the data would it be filter from database or just from the data on the client side?

Comment: Can you be more concrete in your question?

Comment: Unless you make it calling the database when filtering, then no its not filtering from the database.

Comment: @Webbanditten but it would takes a lots of time that when I will type any word it would make ajax call and data will be fetched? and If I fetch all the records from database and paginate them and then filter then It will filter really fast as compare to fetching from database.What you say?

Comment: @DrimadesBoy I am confuse between two things
Should I fetch all records from database and then filter result?
should i fetch records only when user want to filter the data?

Comment: If there isn't alot of data you can make your input autocomplete. Data will be loaded at start so there is no need for AJAX call. If there is alot of data to process, than filter data in SQL query and limit result to some number. Loading 200k rows in array or any collection will use alot of resources, filtering that big array will use even more.

Comment: @MatteoKovacic I have 15,000 records to show and If I dont apply server side and only rely on client side in the datatable would it work fine?

Comment: I would recommend server side, loading at start is usually for small amout of data, for example name of categories or countries.

Comment: @MatteoKovacic but there is another question that filtering in this big amount of records and then fetching the result will be very time and resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX request to method which will send query to your database with condition and getting limited number of results is probably the best way. Ajax response will be in around 300ms-500ms.

Comment: So I would show the records on pagination button click from one query and fetch the records for the filteration result from another query.Is this you are talking about?

Comment: If you are using some framework, they have pagination integrated so you just need to return result set that you get from query. If not, than there is alot of plugins to do the same thing. Ofcourse, you can do that manually with SQL "LIMIT" and "OFFSET" in your query. For exampe LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 will return you rows from 11 to 20 (this is page 2 if you put your pagination to limit of 10 results per page)